# Why exactly this will not compile if (a) b = c, d = e, return;?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operators

I am addicted to "braceless" ifs, like this:

```
if (a) b++, c++, d = e;
```

But one annoying thing is that `return` cannot be a part of the last part. Intuitively I feel why is that, but can anyone explain in programming language terms why this will not compile?

```
main() {
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    if (a) b = c, d = e, return;
}
```

If you care, please also explain why is that designed like that, it seems like a flaw to me. I can understand in C but in C++ it could have been redesigned without major compatibility loss with the existing C code.

Just for comparison: these will compile and do exactly what expected:

```
while (a < 10) a++, b--, c += 2;

while (a < 10) if (a == 5) half = a, save();
```

Comment: You are on Santa's naughty list.

Comment: `return b = c, d = e;` doesn't float your boat? It doesn't float mine, but neither do those commas for braceless ifs.

Comment: This is just evil - I would not hire you if you write code like this.

Comment: @chris: Note that only works if the function return type matches the result of the expression.

Comment: Because the designers thought that `if (a) [&]{ b = c, d = e; return; }();` provides sufficient functionality (warning: read with care :)). Alternatively you can write `if (a) return b = c, d = e, void();`

Comment: @Cornstalks, Well, you can always append something else to appease that while you're being evil.

Comment: Why would you want to test the value of an uninitialized variable to initialize 2 other variables the values of 2 uninitialized variables? This whole thing reeks.

Comment: @chris What would you suggest for a `void` function? (Apart from the obvious “don’t do this, argh, that hurts my eyes!”)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Holy crap, you can do `void()`?! I never knew!

Comment: @Cornstalks, Yeah, rarely useful, but possible nonetheless.

Comment: Urgs. Evil teh above lambda, it will not return the main function. :)

Comment: naughty, ugly, evil... you discourage me asking questions

Comment: Next time when you ask question then please do not tag it with both C and C++ together.

Comment: @exebook: While I don't agree with the downvotes (whether the style is good or bad, it is a valid question), I do agree with the qualifiers to the code. Do you find that code more readable than the equivalent with braces? Do you think someone maintaining your code would? Is the intention in the format anything other than attempting to be *clever*? (i.e. I know I can do weird things that will surprise others!) Without any justification the code does look *naughty, evil and ugly*.

Comment: nobody ever reads my code. and for me I just do not need to press SHIFT, and personally I find it easier to comprehend what the code does, curly braces just throw one extra component to the equation that my brain must solve. but this has nothing to do with the question, I just asked why it won't compile, I do not promote this kind of coding style in any way.

Comment: WHo would write code like that?  Someone who wants to get fired?

Comment: The code samples in the OP are ugly, but do you really think that `if (simple test) a++, b++;` looks so terrible?

Comment: Also, I think the downvotes are a response to the coding style and not the question.  The question itself is a good one, asked in good faith, with a non-obvious answer.

Comment: @exebook Take a look at python, it doesn't have braces and is kinda similar to c.

Comment: Python absolutely has braces. They're just expressed slightly differently (with indentation). But conceptually, it completely has braces.

Comment: @DeadMG I think it is pretty obvious I'm talking about the actual sign braces `{}` not some metaphorical concept.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The "comma" operator is exactly that, an operator. It's left and right sides must be expressions, and `return` is not an expression.

To elaborate, the comma operator evaluates its left-hand side first, and discards the value. Then, it evaluates its right-hand side, and the whole comma expression evaluates to the right-hand side's value.

It's similar to this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
U operator,(T t, U u)
{
    return u;
}
```

Therefore, you cannot put anything in a comma expression that is not an expression itself.

If you're looking to simultaneously execute a series of statements and group them together, that's exactly what `;` and `{}` are for. There is no reason to duplicate that behavior in the comma operator.

Comment: This only really explains the *what*, not the *why*.

Comment: You can't pass a `void` expression to a function, but it can still be used in a (non-overloaded) comma-operator.

Comment: interesting, but wasn't an idea to make a comma into an operator weird from the beginning? in natural language, in math notation, in C itself (when you declare variables) comma is rather a delimiter, it would have been more logical to make comma to separate and connect expressions rather than be an operator within an expression with an obscure semantics?

Comment: @DeadMG: This answers perfectly well and clearly "why" the statement does not compile, which is the primary question.

Comment: @exebook I believe that the semicolon `;` fills that role pretty well. Semicolon separates expressions, and braces `{}` connect them.

Comment: Saying "The statement does not compile because the language is designed that way" doesn't really explain why the language is designed that way.

Comment: @DeadMG: First, nobody said that. Second, "Why the language is designed that way" is a secondary question. The primary question is about why it will not compile. This question answers that, and it doesn't say anything remotely equivalent to "The statement does not compile because the language is designed that way".

Comment: @DeadMG In addition to what Benjamin Lindley has already stated, I don't think it's possible to answer exactly why the comma operator was designed like this, without asking the person who designed it. There may not even be a reason; perhaps the designer didn't even think about it. It's certainly possible (although unlikely) that the language may be modified to allow such usage of the comma operator in the future.

Comment: Literally or not, "It doesn't compile because the language is not designed that way" is what is written here. All the answer has done is paraphrase from the specification.

Comment: @DeadMG After reading your answer to the question, I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. My answer may be, "Because the language is not designed that way," but your answer is, "Because nobody wants the language to be designed that way." I fail to see any real difference between our answers.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done the following way

```
if (a) return ( b = c, d = e, 0 );
```

Oe if there is no return expression

```
if (a) return ( b = c, d = e, ( void )0 );
```

Answer (score 5):

It may be open to question whether this answers the question the OP was really asking, but in case anybody cares about why the comma operator was designed the way it was, I think it goes back to BCPL.

In BCPL, you could combine a series of assignments like:

```
L1 := R1
L2 := R2
```

...into a single statement (command) like:

```
L1, L2 := R1, R2
```

Much like in C and C++, these were executed in order from left to right. Unlike C and C++, this "comma operator" didn't produce a single expression (at least as C uses the term).

BCPL also had a `resultis` that let you make a block of statements into something almost like a function.

At least to me, it looks like in C, Dennis<sup>1</sup> decided decided to sort of combine these two concepts into a single one that was rather simpler: a comma operator that would allow evaluation of a number of expressions in succession, and yield a single result.

Reference: [BCPL Reference Manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/bcpl.pdf)

---

1. I suppose in fairness I should mention the possibility that this decision was actually made by Ken Thomson in the design of B. Little enough documentation on B has survived that it's almost impossible to even guess about that.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated `return` is not an expression, it's a keyword. However, `b = c, d = e` *is* an expression. Therefore your intent is probably this:

```
if (a) return (b = c, d = e, 0);
```

`b = c, d = e, return` doesn't really make any sense, as it would be inconsistent with how the comma operator works in other contexts. Imagine if you could do this:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0, return; ...
```

That would make absolutely no sense. It would also be redundant if `return` meant something in this context as the comma operator already returns its last operand. There would also be no point because the comma operator already evaluates its operands, how would `return something` be beneficial in this case?

Someone looking at your code might glance over it and say, "this should be: `if (a) (b = c, d = e); return 0;`", which is a trap because of the lack of braces. What they would really mean is `if (a) { (b = c, d = e); return 0; }`, but this problem would be avoided if you use the syntax mentioned at the top of this answer. It simply isn't readable as it makes no semantic sense.

Regardless, this would only make sense if `b` and `d` were global variables, for example something like `errno`, allowing you to assign to the variable and return in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

> Why exactly this will not compile if (a) b = c, d = e, return;?

This is because a comma (`,`) operator must have its left and right operands to be **expressions**. The `return` statement is not an expression. See the syntax defined for `,` operator by the C and C++ standard:

### C11: 6.5.17 Comma operator

```
Syntax
      expression:
             assignment-expression
             expression , assignment-expression
```

The same syntax is defined by C++ standard

### C++: 5.18 Comma operator [expr.comma]

> The comma operator groups left-to-right.
>
> ```
>       expression:
>              assignment-expression
>              expression , assignment-expression
> ```
>
> **A pair of expressions**<sub>1</sub> separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right;

Note that the standard says about *expressions* and `return` is not an expression.

---

<sub>1.Emphasis is mine</sub>

Comment: I am again asking downvoters please leave a comment.

Comment: I downvoted because the question is about C++ and you have quoted the C Standard.

Comment: @DeadMG; Then why the question is tagged with C++? Ask the OP.

Comment: @DeadMG: Though the section number changes to 5.18, the C++ standard gives identical syntax.

Comment: I admit, my comment was in error. The question asks "Why?". The Standard says "What". This is equally true for both Standards.

Comment: @JerryCoffin; Thanks for the C++ reference.

Answer (score 0):

> I can understand in C but in C++ it could have been redesigned without
>   major compatibility loss with the existing C code.

It *could* have been, but why would anyone, ever, want it to be? The language already contains a means to the end that you are looking for- braces. They are much more reliable and useful than abusing the comma operator like you have. For example, if you are using UDTs, then you are going to run into some nasty surprises when I overload the comma operator. Oops!

More to the point, having `return` as an expression doesn't make sense, because the function has already, well, returned, when it is evaluated, so there's no way anyone could possibly use any hypothetical return value.

Your entire question is predicated on your personal dislike of braces. Nobody else who designs the language really shares that feeling.